# How to use tabs in Latex?

Tags: spacing

I don't want to use the `\equation` tag. But I want to write as follow:

```
Set of equations: x = y + 5
                  y = 3
```

I tried the alignment operator (`&`) but didn't work out. I tried `\quad`, `\tab`, but also couldn't get it. I tried `\begin{itemize}`, but it goes usually on new line, and I want the first equation on the same line.

Comment: There's an important distinction as to whether the equations should be part of a paragraph of text (as in Schrödinger's cat's answer), or whether "Set of equations:" should be part of a displayed set of equations (as in the other three answers).  You've not said which, but should be aware of the difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome! You can use the `aligned` environment with `[t]` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Set of equations: $\begin{aligned}[t]x &= y + 5\\
                  y &= 3\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the standard [`tabbing`](https://latexref.xyz/tabbing.html#tabbing) environment for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  Set of equations: \= $x = y + 5$ \\
                    \> $y = 3$     \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with `flalign(*)`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
.........
\begin{flalign*}
&\rlap{Set of equations:} & x &= y + 5 & \\
              & &   y &= 3
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it should be displayed math, you might just use `align` (or if the equations shouldn't be numbered `align*` instead):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{Set of equations:}\quad
  x &= y + 5 \\
  y &= 3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]